# Add multiple records from subform to main form Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to add multiple data that has been selected from a subform to the main form?

[image: Subform data to main form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select data it is better to use a listfield
and then copy the data with a VB program in the table:

```
set rs1=currendb.openrecordset ("NAME OF TABLE)
For Z = 0 To Me.ListField.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListField.Selected(Z) = True Then
        Rs1.addnew 
        rs1!field1 = Me.LisField.Column(0, Z)
        rs1!field2 = Me.LisField.Column(1, Z)     
    End If
next z
```

Answer (score 1):

Form.SelTop and .SelHeight are the key properties here.

Example with a subform.RecordsetClone loop:

```vb
Set F = Me.Subform.Form
Set RS = F.RecordsetClone
RS.MoveFirst
' goto first selected record
RS.Move F.SelTop - 1
' loop over all selected records
For i = 1 To F.SelHeight
    ' do something with fields from RS
    RS.MoveNext
Next i
```